# Ranorex error, method name is not valid

Tags: automated-testing, ranorex

I am working on a test automation project, which I have built a code module collection for. In this collection:

- I have a method named "`Click_on_new_button`"

But when I attempted to use this method in a recording, Ranorex told me,

- Method name is not valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a long shot, but can you please try removing all of your underscores from your method name?

- ClickOnNewButton

Ranorex has a quirk that occasionally forces you to play with method names, there is nothing wrong with your naming, it is Ranorex's problem.

Hope it helps.